# What is wrong with my Python 3x code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have code like that,

```
database = open("C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\database.txt", "w")
enter=input("What is your name: ")
database.write(enter)
database.close
```

When I run the this program, it does not print anything in database.txt

I trying with IDLE and PyScripter but I have same result :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand "database" is just a nick for the file...

```
database = open("C:/Users/PC/Desktop/database.txt", "w")
enter=input("What is your name: ")
database.write(enter)
database.close()
```

Answer (score 6):

Change `database.close` to `database.close()`. You aren't calling the method.

I suggest using Python's context manager for this. The file will be automatically closed for you.

```
with open("C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\database.txt", "w") as database:
    enter = input("What is your name: ")
    database.write(enter)
```

Answer (score 2):

Close is a method so you should invoke it:

```
database = open(r"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\database.txt", "w")
enter=input("What is your name: ")
database.write(enter)
database.close()
```